# How to program a walk cycle in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game in Pygame and would like to program a walk cycle. How do I do this?

I'm making this game for a game jam, and I'm reusing some code from a tutorial I went through. The code should have been adjusted as much as it needed to be, but my code won't work.

```
def draw(self, win):
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])
    if self.walkCount + 1 >= 20:
        self.walkCount = 0

    walkDown = [pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF0.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF1.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF2.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF3.png")]
    walkRight = []
    walkLeft = []
    walkUp = []
    if not(self.standing):
        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.down:
            win.blit(walkDown[self.walkCount//4])
    else:
        if self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            win.blit(walkDown[0], (self.x, self.y))
```

The result should create a walking animation where each frame lasts for 4 frames. However, the code returns an index error:

```
File "/home/runner/classes.py", line 35, in draw
win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//4], (self.x, self.y))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The list has 4 elements and `self.walkCount` is a continuously increasing.
You don't have to calculate the quotient of `self.walkCount` divided by 4. You have to calculate the remainder of the division by 4. 
Use the modulo operator (`%`) instead of the integral division operator (`//`). See [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

It has to be

`walkLeft[self.walkCount % 4]`

rather than

<s>`walkLeft[self.walkCount // 4]`</s>

---

Don't continuously load the images in `draw()`. Load the images in the constructor of the class and use them in the `draw()` method:

e.g.

```py
__init__(self):

    # [...]

    self.walkDown = [pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF0.png"), 
        pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF1.png"), 
        pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF2.png"), 
        pygame.image.load("sprites/MaleMCWalkF3.png")]

def draw(self, win):

    # [...]


    if not(self.standing):
        if self.left:

            win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount % 4], (self.x, self.y))

    # [...]
```

Comment: I don't get an index error, but the walk cycle doesn't happen. It just shows the first frame.

Comment: @RyanCrank do you call draw in a loop? Is there a `pygame.display.flip()` in the loop?

Comment: I call the draw in a function I have. I do not use a `pygame.display.flip` anywhere.

Comment: I have defined the walkDown variable up where you said to. I also noticed an issue with my programming for the walk cycle and resolved the issue. The animation still does not work. The same issue is persisting, where the first frame exists but there is no cycle.

Comment: @RyanCrank I can only see the small snippet of code from your question. It is impossible to say where your issue is.

Comment: What would you like me to do about that? Should I upload what I have to a Github repository and send you a link?

Comment: @RyanCrank Is it more than 1 file?